# Is there a way to insert between Meteor templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I am trying to insert advertising blocks in a Meteor list template. The code will show it more easily than I can describe:

```
// dataList.js
  Template.dataList.helpers({

    dataList : function() {
      return DataList.find();
    });

// dataList.html
  <template name="dataList">
    {{#each dataList}}
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        {{name}} (and other data)
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </template>
```

The result I want is something like this

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
  Jon Snow
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">    <----This inserted programmatically 
  <div id="ad">
     Buy a Destrier - 5 Golden Stags
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
  Tyrion Lannister
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
  The Hound
</div>
```

The effect is similar to the advertising found on [Foodgawker.com](http://foodgawker.com/). I can't work out how to insert the ads programmatically at random intervals.
This is on an infinite scroll and will need to add the Ad several times.

Answer (score 0):

## New Idea

```
// client side collection, not synchronized with server side...
DataListWithAds= new Mongo.Collection(null);

Template.DataList.destroyed= function(){
  this.observer.stop();
}
Template.DataList.created= function(){
    // DataList is collection anywhere
    // get handler of observer to remove it later...
    this.observer = DataList.find().observe({

        // observe if any new document is added
        // READ : http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe

        addedAt:function(document, atIndex, before){
          console.log(atIndex, document, self);

          // immediately insert original document to DataListWithAds collection
          DataListWithAds.insert(document);

          // if some condition is true, then add ad.
          if(atIndex % 5 == 1){
            DataListWithAds.insert({
              name:"AD", score:document.score, isAd:true
            });
          }
        }
      }) 
}


  // use local collection to display items together with ads

  Template.dataList.helpers({
    dataList : function() {
      return DataListWithAds.find();
    });
  })
```

Also template should be tweaked a little bit:

```
<template name="dataList">
    {{#each dataList}}
       {{#if isAd}}
           ADVERTISEMENT
      {{else}}
         <div class="col-xs-3">
            {{name}} (and other data)
          </div>
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </template>
```

Proof of concept can be found here:
http://meteorpad.com/pad/SoJe9dgp644HKQ7TE/Leaderboard

I think there are still things to resolve, like:
- How to make this working together with sorting ?

## Old Idea

Below is an **idea** how you can achieve result you want.

The approach is that client side waits until your list is rendered (happens only once) and then injects an **ad** at position of your choice.

Assumptions:

- your ad is defined in template **adsTemplate**
- items are in div : **#listContainer**

Code:

```
Template.dataList.rendered = function(){
  // position after which ads should be added
  // you can generate random number
  var adsPosition = 10;

  // inject HTML from template **Template.adsTemplate**
  // with data **adsData** 
  // to HTML element #listContainer
  // after HTML element at position adsPosition
  Blaze.renderWithData(
    Template.adsTemplate,
    adsData,
    this.find('#listContainer'),
    this.find('#listContainer .col-xs-3:nth-child('+adsPosition+')')
  )
}
```

If you want to inject many ads, because **list** should be infinite , then it is good idea to use [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) to detect new data and inject accordingly.

Comment: Have you run this in the wild?  I would expect the 'dataList' template to be rendered before all docs in the each loop ( `#listContainer` ) are rendered.  Does that lead to flicker?

Comment: I failed to mention this was on an infinite scroll. This solution will not insert an ad multiple times

Comment: I like this method the best, however I still cannot get it to permanently display. It briefly shows the adsTemplate then when data is loaded you can't see it anymore

Comment: @Kuba Wyrobek It is adding the Template.adsTemplate, however it ends up at the bottom of the #listContainer. It is not taking the adsPosition into account

Comment: I have updated my answer which seems to be much better, you don't need to mess with HTML directly. You simply create new local collection and fill it at right index. Blaze takes care about proper rendering. Good luck with it !

Answer (score 0):

You can randomly choose an _id from your list and just display the ad after that doc in the template.

Like this:

```
//.js
Template.dataList.created = function(){
  var ids = DataList.find().map( function( doc ){ return doc._id });
  this.showAdId = Random.choice( ids ); //need to add 'random' package of meteor core
};

Template.dataList.helpers({
  dataList: function(){
    return DataList.find({},{transform: function( doc ){
      doc.showAd = doc._id === Template.instance().showAdId;
      return doc;
    });
  }
});

//.html 
<template name="dataList">
  {{#each dataList}}
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      {{name}} (and other data)
    </div>
    {{#if showAd}}  <!-- check new field to see whether this is the doc with an ad -->
      <div class="col-xs-3">    
        <div id="ad">
          Buy a Destrier - 5 Golden Stags
        </div>
      </div>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are too complex ; just update your helper :

```
dataList : function() {
  var d = _.map( DataList.find().fetch(), function(v) { return {value: v}; });
  return _.union( d.slice(0,2), {
    type: 'ad',
    value: 'Buy a Destrier - 5 Golden Stags'
  } ,d.slice(2));
});
```

So, dataList will have the ad inserted in third position.

Comment: You should probably mention the drawbacks with this solution (no fine grained updates).